# Process post request with rails

Tags: ios, ajax, json, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

A little background info so you can know my overall goal:

I have a web app that uses rails and Devise for authentication. I also am making an iPhone app which I need to be able to send and retrieve data to/from this app. I've decided to make a custom token authentication system in order to handle this.

I want to be able to send a username and password in JSON format as a post request to my app, have the app get that username and password, then have the app reply with a token in an xml or JSON format.

How do I make an action that will get information from a post request (username and password) and process it then return something else?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Or have any codes to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just recently attended a meetup that explained [Helios](https://github.com/helios-framework/helios), which sounds like what you are looking for.

Check out their docs. Also this [Github](https://github.com/thedevme/helios-demo/) is an example of helios in action.